# How many Stack Overflow users are male?

Tags: discussion, users, statistics

Is there any place to see charts about the demographics of Stack Overflow users such as countries, or sex, or the spread of reputation around the globe? Specifically I'd like to know the comparison between males and females.

Comment: Not sure but from what I gather this may be as close as you'll get: https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com#!demo

Comment: It says 91% male!!  is it reliable??

Comment: [exact dupe](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283364/what-percentage-of-female-so-accounts-exists-as-compared-to-males) >10 kers only..

Comment: @Avinash quick hit that undelete button so we can see it

Comment: [On the Internet, nobody knows you're a dog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog).

Comment: @PeterJ  i don't want to get downvotes :-)

Comment: Quantcast is of course not reliable. It simply makes a guess based on data mining, which can be accurate or horribly wrong. There is no way to know the percentage of males if you don't propose asking every single user, thus this question is unanswerable.

Comment: And why do you want to know that? Suppose the answer is 42. What does that tell you? What's next?

Comment: Btw, any gender guess made by quantcast is probably biased, especially with regard to IT sites. Many people use SO from work, where they can't or won't use the internet for private matters. But if a male and female person both google the same technical terms and end up on the same quantcast-mined IT sites, quantcast will probably guess their gender as male because that's demographically more likely.

Comment: If you're just interested in some stats you can fiddle with the [data available in SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/265213#graph) ...

Comment: We only really care about what an SO user has between his ears.  It would perhaps be mildly interesting if somebody with 6 fingers can type faster.  Other body parts are totally irrelevant.

Comment: @rene, just what I was looking for awesome that SO has this feature!!

Comment: SO is 93% Male, according to it's own Developer Survey (this has held relatively consistent across the few years I've browsed): https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#developer-profile-gender

Answer (score 14):

There's no sex (gender) information in your SO profile, so there's no way to get what users state. You could try profile pictures (roughly 7% of SO are unicorns) or nicknames (roughly 30% of SO are `user\d+`), but... yeah.

<sub>All statistics are made up.</sub>

Comment: I'm a male and a total fan of unicorns, just saying. :-)

Comment: yeah, profile picture. [Like this one](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0f/20140321_Dancing_Stars_Conchita_Wurst_4187.jpg/170px-20140321_Dancing_Stars_Conchita_Wurst_4187.jpg)

Comment: I'm a male **and** a unicorn, @KevinVoorn. Just saying. ;-)

Comment: You're an evil unicorn @AndrewBarber, that doesn't count :o

Comment: Hmph. The truth hurts. @KevinVoorn

Comment: This data is now available in the Developer Survey, which says that SO is 93% Male (this has held relatively consistent across the few years I've browsed): https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#developer-profile-gender